# App crashes when the server is not available. How to set the connectiontimeout for httpurlconnection?

Tags: java, android, exception, httpurlconnection, connection-timeout

```
 String urlStr = "nana.com/nana/api/v1"
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
BufferedReader rd = null;
StringBuilder sb = null;
try {
    URL url = new URL(urlStr);
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        throw new IOException(conn.getResponseMessage());
    }
    else {

    rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    } 
    rd.close();

    conn.disconnect();
    }
} catch (IOException i) {
    i.printStackTrace();
                }catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
```

This is my connection and I don't really want to use apache. I want my application to display some error message if the server is unreachable but instead it crashes and I am sort of out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
try {
            String urlStr = "nana.com/nana/api/v1";
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            BufferedReader rd = null;
            StringBuilder sb = null;

            URL url = new URL(urlStr);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android Application");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            conn.setConnectTimeout(10 * 1000);
            conn.connect();
            if (conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        conn.getInputStream()));
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                rd.close();

                conn.disconnect();

            }else{
                throw new IOException(conn.getResponseMessage());
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```